# How to use setup with timeit in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code that can't make it work. I do not know what i am doing wrong, but the timeit does not work it says that the random is not defined.

```
   import random 
   import timeit 

   set = '''
   def test():
      randomize = [random.randint(0, 30) for y in range(50)]
      function1(randomize)
   '''

   def function1(item):
   ######

   time= timeit.Timer('test()', setup=set)
   print time.repeat(4,200)
```

Comment: Have you tried making `set` a raw string? Like this: `set = r'''something'''`

Comment: still it doesn't work..

Comment: You need to `import random` and define `function1` in the setup as well. Or, the setup can be `'from __main__ import random, test, function1'`.

Comment: You don't even need that much; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import random
import timeit


def test():
    randomize = [random.randint(0, 30) for y in range(50)]
    function1(randomize)


def function1(item):
    return sorted(item)  # something to do


timer = timeit.Timer('test()', setup='from __main__ import test')

print(timer.repeat(4, 200))
```

`from __main__ import test` imports the `test()` function into the timer's scope; it's able to access everything else the same way any function imported from a module is able to access things in the module scope.